# Compare vectors, photo mosaic

Tags: algorithms, image-processing

I’m trying to make a photo mosaic web application. I split the main picture in to a number of squares. I split this square up in to 9 squares.

[image: See picture]

Then I calculate the mean color (RGB) of the entire square and the mean color of the 9 little squares. So I will get the following vector.

Vector: Mean R; mean G; mean B; cell 1 R; cell 1 G; cell 1 B; cell 2 R; cell 2 G; cell 2 B; cell 3 R; cell 3 G; cell 3 B; cell 4 R; cell 4 G; cell 4 B; cell 5 R; cell 5 G; cell 5 B; cell 6 R; cell 6 G; cell 6 B; cell 7 R; cell 7 G; cell 7 B; cell 8 R; cell 8 G; cell 8 B; cell 9 R; cell 9 G; cell 9 B

This will all be number between 0 and 255. And the mean RGB is more important than the other elements.

I make the same vector for all pictures in my DB. So now I want to compare a square of the original too my DB and want to find the 10 closest pictures.

My question is how do I compare these vectors??

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.drdobbs.com/understanding-photomosaics/184404848?pgno=1

Comment: For a single pixel/little square the simplest method probably is to calculate the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance). You could then compare two big squares by how much their sums of those distances differ.